# Getting "Response is stale" from Squid proxy

Tags: nginx, squid

I'm looking at the logs in Chrome dev tools. I can also see it using curl. Here is the output of curl

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Sat, 24 Sep 2016 01:16:37 GMT
ETag: "a02d00a09b8139b0919567e4c92cc752"
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 22:57:56 GMT
Server: nginx
x-amz-id-2: L3gfIQNLcBLUZ2gtVWDiIdN9xWWiV2H6K6zjjE9JSHVMnDXI6+uLuhqptqQRCZLNFoMmWg3mIQs=
x-amz-request-id: E38062B3D506DF06
Content-Length: 1940494
Age: 7574
Warning: 110 squid/3.5.20 "Response is stale"
X-Cache: HIT from 0.0.0.0
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from 0.0.0.0:3128
Via: 1.1 0.0.0.0 (squid/3.5.20)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why is Squid saying `Warning: 110 squid/3.5.20 "Response is stale"`?

Comment: I looked up synonyms of `stale`. It says old. That warning then is fine since I have not updated the .js file. That means, our squid is working fine. However, I wish Squid didn't include it in the headers or maybe there were more people who wanted to see the warning rather than to people who complained seeing the warning. I'll be fine with it for now. I'll post in few weeks if ever there will be users who will start complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid adds this header because it is required by the HTTP caching specifications. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.5.0:

> The "Warning" header field is used to carry additional information
> about the status or transformation of a message that might not be
> reflected in the status code.  This information is typically used to
> warn about possible incorrectness introduced by caching operations or
> transformations applied to the payload of the message.

and section 5.5.1 simply states that caches are required (SHOULD) to send the 110 warning when HIT objects are stale. "SHOULD" RFC requirements are ones that have to be followed unless a specific, very good and documented reason exists not to. Warnings are informative, so there is no good reason to avoid them.

Stale content is not just old, but also past a point where the cache was supposed to ask a server if there is a newer copy (revalidation). So the warning is saying that if you actually *had* updated the server copy the cache would still have delivered the old version of it. That is potentially a very serious breakage in HTTP application behaviour, particularly when .js is involved.

This situation is usually caused by the administrator configuring some refresh_pattern setting that violates the HTTP requirements for revalidation. For example the ignore-* options to force an object to be served as-is from cache instead of revalidating.

Since this response has no Cache-Control header the refresh_pattern min/pct/max values are what Squid uses to calculate the age of staleness. You may want to consider increasing those values to make the objects normal HIT lifetimes longer instead of ignoring/violating HTTP requirements.